# List comprehension-like approach for numpy arrays with more than one dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a list of 2d numpy arrays of the same height but not width:

```
list_of_arrays = [np.random.rand(3,4),np.random.rand(3,5),np.random.rand(3,6)]
```

I want to build a new array where each column is a random column of the arrays in my list. I can do this with a for loop, eg:

```
new_array = np.zeros((3,3))
for x in range(3):
    new_array[:,x] = list_of_arrays[x][:,random.randint(0,list_of_arrays[x].shape[1])]
```

This does not feel clean to me. I would like to use a list comprehension-like approach, eg

```
new_array = [list_of_arrays[x][:,random.randint(0,list_of_arrays[x].shape[1])] for x in range(3)]
```

Which obviously returns a list, not an array as desired. I could convert the list into an array, but that adds an extraneous intermediate. Is there a simple way to do this? Similar questions that I have seen working with 1d arrays use numpy.fromiter, but that will not work in 2 dimensions.

If anyone wants to suggest entirely different/cleaner/more efficient ways to solve this problem, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Nothing wrong about wrapping a list of lists in `np.array`.  `numpy` does that all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your list comprehension simpler by iterating over the arrays instead of the index,

```
new_array = np.array([x[:,np.random.randint(0, x.shape[1])] for x in list_of_arrays]).T

In [32]: %timeit np.array([x[:,np.random.randint(0, x.shape[1])] for x in a]).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.2 us per loop
```

The transposes (`.T`) are because iterating through an array yields the rows, so iterating through `arr.T` yields the columns.  Likewise, when constructing arrays, each element is considered a row, so after construction, we need to transpose it so the lists we feed the array construct are transformed to columns.

If you import the standard `random` module, you could do

```
new_array = np.array([random.choice(x.T) for x in list_of_arrays]).T

In [36]: %timeit np.array([random.choice(x.T) for x in a]).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.18 us per loop
```

which is slightly faster.

Comment: Using iterating over the arrays and using `random.choice` are definitely nice improvements- thanks for those tips. However, if I'm not mistaken, this is generating a list of columns and then converting it to an ndarray. If possible, I'd like to cut out the middleman here, so to speak.

Comment: @Joe, you're starting with a `list`, so at some point you're calling `np.ndarray`, whether or not you mask it in a `np.*stack` or `np.zeros`.

Comment: What I was hoping to avoid was generating a second list to hold the array slices pulled from the first list- I was hoping to speed things up by sticking those straight into an array. However, given further research on the way memory is allocated for arrays and @hpaulj's comment above, it seems like that intermediate list is actually important. So, I'll use this code and look for performance gains elsewhere in my script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you combine the arrays into another array rather than a list?

```
>>> b= np.hstack((np.random.rand(3,4),np.random.rand(3,5),np.random.rand(3,6)))
>>> b.shape
(3, 15)
```

Then you can use [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), as opposed to list comprehension, to pick random columns:

```
new_array=b[:,np.random.randint(0,b.shape[1],3)]
```

Comment: The issue here is that I need exactly one column from each of my initial arrays, rather than any three columns, which is what your method looks like it produces. I could have the code remember which "block" corresponds to which initial array, but given that I could have any number of arrays each with any number of columns that could get complicated fast.